# FIWARE object storage GE: Different type of responses obtained when downloading an image object

Tags: object, storage, fiware

I can effectively make use of all operations available for Object Storage on my FIWARE account.

Nonetheless I have identified a strange behaviour when downloading objects from a container.

Please find below the procedure to reproduce that strange behaviour:

1. I upload two objects ("gonzo.png" and "elmo.png") to the container "photos"

   1.1. First, by means of cloud UI (https://cloud.lab.fiware.org/#objectstorage/containers/) I manually upload the object "gonzo.png"

   1.2. Later, by following the instructions from Object Storage GE programmer's guide I programmatically (or with the help of standalone Rest Client) upload the object "elmo.png"
2. I download the objects from the container "photos"

   2.1 First, by following the instructions from Object Storage GE programmer's guide I successfully download object "gonzo.png". The webservice response body is the binary content of such object.

   2.2. Later, by following same instructions as in step 2.1 I try to download the object "elmo.png". Now the webservice response body is a json with metadata and the binary content of the object.

What can I do receive a standard response body for both objects? Either binary or either json.

Why do I get a different response if the object is originally uploaded via Cloud UI or via external tool (program or rest client) ?

As in [Download blob from fiware object-storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24436153/download-blob-from-fiware-object-storage) I have already tried to set the header *response_type: text* and the behaviour is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many object stores out there, having different APIs.
The Object Storage GE was initially based on the CDMI API [1].
Currently, it is based on Openstack Swift [2].
The Cloud Portal still uses some of the CDMI features and specifically it may do 64-bit encoding of some types of objects in which case the object content is a json which contains the metadata and a base64 encoding of the data. I suspect that this is what happened to the object you have created using the cloud UI.

Thus, please use Swift native API for all operations.
The API is well documented here: http://developer.openstack.org/api-ref-objectstorage-v1.html
and the python examples in the programmer guide (https://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Object_Storage_-_User_and_Programmers_Guide) also use the Native API.

[1] google for SNIA CDMI. Having less then 10 replutation I cannot put too many links
[2] google for Openstack Swift